# JQuery's on() don't work on iOS

Tags: jquery, touch-event

I have a  Javascript that looks like that

```
$(document).on("click", "#nearLines", function () {
    $("#loadingAnim").show();
    $("#indexChoices").slideToggle("slow", "swing", function () {
        getNearLines();
    })
});
```

It works well on desktop browsers but on iOS, when tapping on the `div` whose ID is `nearLines` nothing happens. Any idea why ?

PS: I tried it with jquery.min 2.0.3 and 1.9.1.

Comment: I'll have to check at home but my portfolio uses `.on('click', function() {}` for the menu and it works just fine on my iphone.

Comment: Make sure you have no elements containing `#nearLines` that have click handlers that do `event.stopPropagation()`. That will prevent delegation from working.

Comment: I also use .on without problems. It must be something else!

Comment: @Barmar my js is quite simple I don't have these kind of things. @ nmoliveira probably but what ?

Comment: When developping for Mobile with jQuery, it strongly recommended using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) or you will surely encounter more unexpected side-effects...

However, if you [build yourself a small script](http://cubiq.org/do-you-really-need-jquery-for-mobile-dev) to fix jQuery's issues with mobile, you might avoid them...

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange answer but jquery click doesn't play well with ios if your not binding to a anchor tag. It cant tell that your button is a click event so will not do anything.

Try adding this to your css

```
#nearLines{cursor:pointer;}
```

This basically tells ios that your div is a link.

Try the example below on your ipone to see what I mean

http://jsfiddle.net/VncKc/2/

Comment: Well curious anwsers indeed but yeah that "solves" the problem.

Comment: Yer its annoying but in a wierd way makes sense :) to stop the user clickign things by accident when scrolling with there finger etc. I normally try to just bind to anchor links where possible to not run into this problem.

Comment: Hey I found out the navigator sends a `touchstart` instead of a tap or a click (cf http://riccardo.forina.me/handle-click-with-jquery-on-android-gingerbread/ )